# MySQL SUM from multiple columns with different GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, sum, subquery

I have problem with get SUM of the total number of goals scored(Zdobyte) and conceded(Stracone) by each team on both sides, as host(GoleGosp) and as guest(GoleGosc). What im doing wrong ?

For get SUM of goals as HOST i use

```
SELECT CONCAT(Nazwa,' ',Miasto) AS Klub, SUM(GoleGosp) AS Zdobyte,SUM(GoleGosc) AS Stracone FROM mecze JOIN kluby ON mecze.IdGosp=kluby.IdKlub WHERE (IdGosp BETWEEN 1 AND 16) AND IdGosp<>IdGosc GROUP BY CONCAT(Nazwa,' ',Miasto);
```

And for SUM of goals as GUEST i use

```
 SELECT CONCAT(Nazwa,' ',Miasto) AS Klub, SUM(GoleGosc) AS Zdobyte,SUM(GoleGosp) AS Stracone FROM mecze JOIN kluby ON mecze.IdGosc=kluby.IdKlub WHERE (IdGosc BETWEEN 1 AND 16) AND IdGosc<>IdGosp GROUP BY CONCAT(Nazwa,' ',Miasto);
```

I dont know how to SUM both of these queries as one..

This one dont work

```
SELECT DISTINCT ZdobyteGOSP,StraconeGOSP,ZdobyteGOSC,StraconeGOSC FROM

(SELECT CONCAT(Nazwa,' ',Miasto) AS Klub, SUM(GoleGosp) AS ZdobyteGOSP,SUM(GoleGosc) AS StraconeGOSP FROM mecze JOIN kluby ON mecze.IdGosp=kluby.IdKlub WHERE (IdGosp BETWEEN 1 AND 16) AND IdGosp<>IdGosc GROUP BY CONCAT(Nazwa,' ',Miasto)) as p1,
(SELECT CONCAT(Nazwa,' ',Miasto) AS Klub, SUM(GoleGosc) AS ZdobyteGOSC,SUM(GoleGosp) AS StraconeGOSC FROM mecze JOIN kluby ON mecze.IdGosc=kluby.IdKlub WHERE (IdGosc BETWEEN 1 AND 16) AND IdGosc<>IdGosp GROUP BY CONCAT(Nazwa,' ',Miasto)) as p2;
```

.

```
'CREATE TABLE `mecze` (
  `IdGosp` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `IdGosc` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Datameczu` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `GoleGosp` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `GoleGosc` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `IleWidzow` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  KEY `IdGosp` (`IdGosp`),
  KEY `IdGosc` (`IdGosc`),
  CONSTRAINT `mecze_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`IdGosc`) REFERENCES `kluby` (`IdKlub`),
  CONSTRAINT `mecze_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`IdGosp`) REFERENCES `kluby` (`IdKlub`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8'
'CREATE TABLE `kluby` (
  `IdKlub` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT ''0'',
  `Nazwa` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Miasto` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `RokZal` varchar(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`IdKlub`)


) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8'
```

INSERTS

```
INSERT INTO kluby (IdKlub,Nazwa,Miasto,RokZal) VALUES
(1,'Wisla','Krakow',1933),
(2,'Slask','Wroclaw',1947),
(3,'Legia','Warszawa',1945),
(4,'Lech','Poznan',1950),
(5,'Stomil','Olsztyn',1962),
(6,'Lechia','Gdansk',1949),
(7,'Rokita','Brzeg Dolny',1951),
(8,'Izolator','Boguchwala',1955),
(9,'LKS','Lodz',1946),
(10,'Gornik','Zabrze',1948),
(11,'Groclin','Grodzisk',1977),
(12,'Wisla','Plock',1932),
(13,'Cracovia','Krakow', 1925),
(14,'Korona','Kielce',1933),
(15,'Jagiellonia','Bialystok',1954),
(16,'Unia','Raciborz',1950);

INSERT INTO mecze (IdGosp,IdGosc,Datameczu,GoleGosp,GoleGosc,IleWidzow) values
(10,14,'2009-01-25',2,2,9830),
(11,14,'2009-02-01',2,2,1876),
(12,14,'2009-02-08',5,1,8670),
(13,14,'2009-02-15',5,3,16969),
(14,14,'2009-02-22',2,5,7688),
(15,1,'2008-10-05',1,2,1222),
(16,2,'2008-10-05',3,0,1899),
(15,3,'2008-10-15',2,1,1333),
(16,4,'2008-10-15',0,5,722),
(5,15,'2008-10-22',1,1,2113),
(6,16,'2008-10-22',1,1,522),
(4,10,'2008-12-28',3,5,6521),
(5,10,'2009-01-04',4,5,6077),
(6,10,'2009-01-11',3,3,10385),
(7,10,'2009-01-18',2,5,8254),
(8,10,'2009-01-25',5,4,9821),
(9,10,'2009-02-01',5,2,3256),
(1,1,'2008-10-04',3,3,5559),
(2,1,'2008-10-05',4,5,7565),
(3,1,'2008-10-12',1,4,8910),
(4,1,'2008-10-19',3,5,1208),
(5,1,'2008-10-26',2,1,6577);
```

Comment: could you apply indentation to your queries as well so they are more readable. and maybe add some insert statements for test data as well and your expected result with that test data.

Comment: Post edited, u got some insert for both tables

Comment: Nice, just set up my own database to test with it. So could you also show or explain better what your expected result would be with this dataset?

Comment: I need SUM results from two first queries in my post but idk how to use these two to make working query. 

I need result like this:

Klub                Zdobyte Stracone
Wisla Krakow     25           20
Slask Wroclaw     30             40

etc. for all 16 teams

Comment: can you check my answer to see if that gives what you wanted ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm thinking this is what you want:

```
SELECT T1.Klub, T1.Zdobyte+IFNULL(T2.Zdobyte,0) AS Zdobyte, T1.Stracone+IFNULL(T2.Stracone,0) AS Stracone
FROM (SELECT idKlub,
        CONCAT(Nazwa,' ',Miasto) AS Klub, 
        SUM(GoleGosp) AS Zdobyte,
        SUM(GoleGosc) AS Stracone 
        FROM mecze 
        JOIN kluby ON mecze.IdGosp=kluby.IdKlub 
        WHERE (IdGosp BETWEEN 1 AND 16) 
        AND IdGosp<>IdGosc GROUP BY CONCAT(Nazwa,' ',Miasto)) AS T1
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT idKlub,
                CONCAT(Nazwa,' ',Miasto) AS Klub, 
                SUM(GoleGosc) AS Zdobyte,
                SUM(GoleGosp) AS Stracone 
                FROM mecze 
                JOIN kluby ON mecze.IdGosc=kluby.IdKlub 
                WHERE (IdGosc BETWEEN 1 AND 16) 
                AND IdGosc<>IdGosp GROUP BY CONCAT(Nazwa,' ',Miasto)) AS T2 ON T2.idKlub = T1.idKlub
```

We use both your queries to set up 2 tables and then we use a `LEFT JOIN` to get them together in one table and Sum the values you wanted.

This query gives a different result, but i'm not sure which of the queries contains a mistake (haven't done any counting as i don't fully understand the data.

Edit: I'm pretty sure this last query is correct now, but please check by counting manually! Your original query didn't show one club because it was left out by a join statement!

```
SELECT  CONCAT(Nazwa,' ',Miasto) AS Klub,
        SUM(GoleGosp) AS Zdobyte,
        SUM(GoleGosc) AS Stracone
FROM (SELECT Nazwa, Miasto, SUM(GoleGosp) AS GoleGosp, SUM(GoleGosc) AS GoleGosc
        FROM kluby 
        JOIN mecze ON mecze.IdGosp=kluby.IdKlub AND mecze.IdGosp BETWEEN 1 AND 16 AND mecze.IdGosp != mecze.IdGosc
        GROUP BY CONCAT(Nazwa,' ',Miasto)
        UNION
        SELECT Nazwa, Miasto, SUM(GoleGosc) AS GoleGosp, SUM(GoleGosp) AS GoleGosc
        FROM kluby 
        JOIN mecze ON mecze.IdGosc=kluby.IdKlub AND mecze.IdGosc BETWEEN 1 AND 16 AND mecze.IdGosp != mecze.IdGosc
        GROUP BY CONCAT(Nazwa,' ',Miasto)) AS T1
GROUP BY CONCAT(Nazwa,' ',Miasto)
```

Comment: I need Zdobyte and Zdobyte2 as one column, same for Stracone and Stracone2

Comment: so what do you expect to happen with the values inside them? do they have to be summed?

Comment: Yes. I need SUM from these two as one column. So result should be like
Klub Zdobyte(as SUM from Zdobyte and Zdobyte2) Stracone(as SUM from Stracone and Stracone2)

Comment: thanks a lot man, but tell me how to make it as view, workbench give me error:Error Code: 1349. View's SELECT contains a subquery in the FROM clause

Comment: mmmm, you'd have to make the same query without using subqueries. Let me try some stuff out.

Comment: I just read that i need make that subqueries as views and then use these views instead subqueries

Comment: Just give me a few more minutes, i think i can make your query a lot more cleaner

Comment: Ok i make it with create two views and use them in query. Thx again for instant help !

Comment: If u make another one it will be great. Im waiting

Comment: mmm, it's hard for me to understand exactly what the variables are for. i don't know if there is a mistake in my new query or in the old one. (It's something with football and goals scored i assume?) I'll post the new query under the old one. but it gives a different result

Comment: There is no way to avoid subquery though i think, i tried to but the second join will create multiple rows for each result.

Comment: I think there is some mistake in my first query because "korona Kielce" doesn't show up

Comment: @Kend3r Try the new query please, your first query didn't retrieve all clubs which made it miss some results in the end.

Comment: Both first and second show all clubs, amount is good, Again thanks.

Comment: the first query is missing "Korona Kielce",11,10 and "Wisla Krakow",17,11

Comment: Both give same results

Comment: not for me and the testdata that you have provided. but I'll leave it to you to figure it out :) good luck!